# Find all positive integers n such that $n^4 + n^3 + 1$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I can’t figure out this number theory question. I think that you should ignore the n^4 part, but I can’t figure out what to do next.

Comment: This has nothing to do with linear algebra, completely lacks any effort and has already been asked (at least a couple of times).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I agree. If this has already been asked before, it doesn't contribute any value to this site.

Comment: @JackD'Azurio  I searched the title and I can't readily find where this has been asked before. I'd like to see how it was answered. Could someone provide a link or citation, please?

Answer (score 2):

If $4n^4+4n^3+4 = (2k)^2$, then notice that $$(2n^2+n-1)^2\leq(2k)^2\leq(2n^2+n)^2.$$

Things should be easy from here.